# Matlab fft() in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, fft

What is the python equivalent to Matlab:

```
Y = fft(X,n,dim)
```

Where `X` is a `64x64` complex double matrix, `n = 64`, and `dim=1`

I tried using `numpy.fft.fft()` however it does not give me the correct results

Comment: please share your attempt

Comment: In what way was it incorrect?

Comment: Please show how you computed the FFT in both MALTAB and Python, and show how the results differ. Don’t expect identical floating-point results, but the should be very close.